# Spinner items Not visible in a dropdown list

Tags: android

I have a spinner containing items from a webservice..

[this is the image for spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0wgZ.png)

the code for this is

```
JsonArrayRequest fillspinner = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_SPINNER_ITEM, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            try{
             for(int i =0;i<=response.length();i++){
                 JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                 names = obj.getString("Name");
                 itemnames.add(names);
             }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,itemnames);
            spinner.setAdapter(adap);
            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    fillspinner.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(fillspinner);
}
```

and my layout.xml is

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context=".ActivityClasses.MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/welbtnmargin">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/btnsepration"
        android:text="-"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Expenses"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/btnsepration"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:ms_arrow_tint="@color/white"
        app:ms_text_color="@color/white"
        app:ms_background_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

my problem is when I click on the spinner, I get output like this.

[there are items in the spinner but they are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lc6e.png)

when I click on the item it get selected in the spinner. But not visible in the dropdown list. I tried to inflate my own layout in the adapter, still getting the same result.

Comment: I think your code is OK , check JSON array response again...

Comment: Did you check that `Name` attr in json response is not empty string?

Comment: i checked it five times. its coming correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using third party Spinner. It requires to insert items a specific way.

```
String[] array = itemnames.toArray(new String[]{});
spinner.setItems(array);
```

https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner

Comment: this method worked for me. i just removed the adapter and set the above code..now displaying...thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use below code;

```
  for (int i = 1; i < cityname.length(); i++) {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = cityname.getJSONObject(i);
            //Adding the name of the Rank to array list
            country.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            autotrno.add(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_RANK));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
        spinner.setAdapter(adap);
```

Comment: Can you explain how is this code different from OP?